# how to use local variable of function outside of that function in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, web-worker

hi everyone I'm facing difficulty while using a local variable of a function outside of it, is there any way to do that.

```
instance.onmessage = (e) => {
  let color = e.data
  return color;
};
```

I'm getting color from `instance.onmessage`  and I have to use this color in the code below.

```
visualLinks.lineStyle(
 2,
 link.edgeType === value ? 0xff0000 : color
);
```

```js
instance.onmessage = (e) => {
   let color=e.data
   return color;
};

visualLinks.lineStyle(
  2,
  link.edgeType === value ? 0xff0000 : color
);
```

I know that this is wrong but I have to perform something like this for reference only, I wrote this code.

Comment: what is `instance`?

Comment: worker.onmessage

Comment: did you know about worker in javascript

Comment: I'm getting value from that function but I'm not able to use that value from outside of  that function is there any way  to do that

Comment: instance.onmessage, like the name suggests, will be tiggerred when you receive a message. So what you can do is do the visualLinks.lineStyle() inside this onmessage callback. One other approach can be to call a function from within onmessage and pass the color to be used there. Also if you can add the acutal code or task you are trying to achieve, that would really help in answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a local variable of a function outside of that function in JavaScript. You could make it a global variable instead:

```js
let color = undefined;
window.onmessage = (e) => {
  color = e.data
};

// THIS WILL NOT WORK (because color is still undefined)
console.log(color);
visualLinks.lineStyle(
  2,
  link.edgeType === value ? 0xff0000 : color
);
```

In the case of your code which uses `onmessage()`, your onmessage callback function won't have been run (your function doesn't run until a message is received) in time for any code right after it.

You could wait to run that code until the message is received by moving it inside of the function.

```
let color = undefined;
window.onmessage = (e) => {
  color = e.data;
  console.log(color);
  visualLinks.lineStyle(
    2,
    link.edgeType === value ? 0xff0000 : color
  );
};
```

If this is too simple an answer to be useful, you may have better luck if you include a more realistic example of what you're trying to do.